# Self-reference in dictionary or alternative

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to place rules into list of dicts, where every dict contains conditions and the rule itself. The problem is that there is no easy way for self reference inside dictionary in this case.

Here in my example I use `dict['condition_1']` but this is of course wrong code, treat it as just a placeholder.

So is there any smart solution for this question? I'm afraid that I'm just stuck on the wrong concept with list of dicts and can't see some more obvious and simple alternative.

```
rules = [
    {
        'condition_1': ['Lorem', 'ipsum'],
        'rule': (lambda message: any(word in message for word in dict['condition_1']))
    },
    {
        'condition_1': ['quis', 'nostrud'],
        'condition_2': ['dolor', 'sit', 'amet'],
        'rule': (lambda message: (any(word in message for word in dict['condition_1'])
                              and all(word in message for word in dict['condition_2'])))
    },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest something like using class as an alternative:

```
class Rules_One:
    def __init__(self, condition, message):
        self.condition = condition
        self.message = message
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "Rules_One"
    
    def run_rule(self):
        return any(word in self.message for word in self.condition)

class Rules_Two:
    def __init__(self, condition1, condition2, message):
        self.condition1 = condition1
        self.condition2 = condition2
        self.message = message
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "Rules_Two"
    
    def run_rule(self):
        return any(word in self.message for word in self.condition1) and all(word in self.message for word in self.condition2)

rules = [
    Rules_One(['Lorem', 'ipsum'], "This is ipsum"), 
    Rules_Two(['quis', 'nostrud'], ['dolor', 'sit', 'amet'], "dolor sit amet quis")
]

print("Result:")
for i in rules:
    print(i, "is", i.run_rule())

#Outputs

Result:
Rules_One is True
Rules_Two is True
```

Comment: I've considered classes as an option but I have about hundred different rules. So I just (unsuccessfully) tried to make my code shorter with that dict construction.

Comment: @Gluck - Ah never mind then I thought you have fewer rules.

Answer (score 1):

How about subclassing `dict` ? You can then assign the values in the constructor, but still have all functionalities of `dict`. The rule is passed in as a string and executed in the `get` method, so that you get the right things.

```py
class DerivedDict(dict)
    def __init__(self, *args, rule="", condition_1=[], condition_2=[], **kwargs)
        dict.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self["condition_1"] = condition_1
        self["condition_2"] = condition_2
        self["rule"] = rule
    
    def __str__(self):
        # This method is for cases as str(derived_dict_object), which, by default, would give <DerivedDict at 0x88ha65bc23afat> or something similar
        return "DerivedDict(" + self["rule"] + ", " + self["condition_1"] + ", " + self["condition_2"] + ")"
    
    def get(self):
        eval("return " + self["rule"]) # convert rule string to code
```

Usage:

```py
message = "Lorem"
rules = [
    DerivedDict(
        condition_1=['Lorem', 'ipsum'],
        # The rule MUST be in quotes !
        rule="any(word in message for word in self['condition_1'])"
        # Note the self['condition_1'] : self will be the created dict later
    ),
    DerivedDict(
        condition_1=['quis', 'nostrud'],
        condition_2=['dolor', 'sit', 'amet'],
        rule="(any(word in message for word in dict['condition_1']) and all(word in message for word in self['condition_2'])))"
    )
]
for rule in rules:
    print(rule.get())
```

EDIT:
My solution can be used for hundreds of different rules, without having to create hundreds of different classes ( ;) @Santee ) !

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's an answer I've just got from Semplar from IT Ukraine guild. It has been tested, works just great without any additional construction and should be taken into account.

```
rules = [
    {
        'condition_1': ['Lorem', 'ipsum'],
        'rule': (lambda message, rules, i: any(word in message for word in rules[i]['condition_1']))
    },
    {
        'condition_1': ['quis', 'nostrud'],
        'condition_2': ['dolor', 'sit', 'amet'],
        'rule': (lambda message, rules, i: (any(condition in message for condition in rules[i]['condition_1'])
                                        and all(condition in message for condition in rules[i]['condition_2']))),
    },
    # ...
]
```

and then you can go through list of rules and check what rule is triggered with:

```
for i, r in enumerate(rules):
    if rules[i]['rule'](message, rules, i):
        print(f"it's rule {i}")
```